# I can not correctly translate the code from MSDN to Delphi. Section DirectShow Step 6. Add Support for COM

Tags: delphi, pascal

Please help me to translate the code. I don't know C++ well, but I know Delphi syntax well. I want to translate code from MSDN:

[Step 6. Add Support for COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/step-6--add-support-for-com).

```cpp
static WCHAR g_wszName[] = L"My RLE Encoder";
CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[] = 
{
  { 
    g_wszName,
    &CLSID_RLEFilter,
    CRleFilter::CreateInstance,
    NULL,
    NULL
  }
};
```

and

```cpp
int g_cTemplates = sizeof(g_Templates) / sizeof(g_Templates[0]);
```

I realized that the first line is a variable. But when translated, it does not work. Error:

> This is a string and you defined it as WCHAR.

Next comes the description of the structure, but I do not know such a form.

The last line is also a variable, but it has a `/` and two values.

In general, I kind of understood the meaning, but do not understand how to write it.

Comment: Interfaces are different since Delphi supports interfaces natively, and therefore might not have exact versions of C++'s COM helpers. Literal translations like Remy's thus can be treacherous. As far as Directshow goes, search for open source Delphi components (like Clootie's or some webcam components like DSPACK). Studying their source might help you to solve problems.

Comment: Really, sometimes they differ greatly. I understand the meaning of the C++ language, and I know Delphi well, I can almost easily understand C++ code, but not translate. But sometimes there are such stupid moments: there was a case, I spent 1 week to put "@" in front of the Api function parameter :). I study DirectShow 5 months (programming 1 year) and MSDN. I have DirectShow components from GitHub. For unknown reasons, there is no "CFactoryTemplate" :/. I decided to go the other way and implement a filter enumerator, but the problem is with the pointer.

Comment: My point is that that symbol might be a part of the C++ preprocessor workarounds for not having interfaces. A language natively support interfacing, and only very little preprocessor like Delphi will then not have that symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code roughly translates to Delphi as follows:

```pascal
const
  g_wszName: PWideChar = 'My RLE Encoder';
var
  g_Templates: array[0..0] of CFactoryTemplate;
...
g_Templates[0].m_Name := g_wszName;
g_Templates[0].m_ClsID := @CLSID_RLEFilter;
g_Templates[0].m_lpfnNew := @CRleFilter.CreateInstance;
g_Templates[0].m_lpfnInit := nil;
g_Templates[0].m_pAMovieSetup_Filter := nil;
```

and

```pascal
var
  g_cTemplates: Integer;
...
//g_cTemplates := SizeOf(g_Templates) div SizeOf(g_Templates[0]);
g_cTemplates := Length(g_Templates);
```

Comment: I have a problem. I took a lot of DSPack from the internet. Unfortunately, there is no `CFactoryTemplate` there. There is `TBCFilterTemplat`e and `TBCClassFactory`. There are no variables inside `TBCFilterTemplate`. When using similar variables from `TBCClassFactory`, an error pops up: Cannot assign to a read-only property. I have searched for this feature in other modules but without success. You don't happen to know where to find this function. It's definitely there, but I can't find it for the third day.